# netbeans on ubuntu font look and feel

Tags: swing, netbeans, netbeans-7

is there any chance to make the font in Netbeans 7.3 under ubuntu 12 to look better??? 
take a look on how the same code looks in eclipse and netbeans 
while both IDEs configured with the same editor fonts settings (monospaced), i tried with other fonts also. it seams like netbeans rendering the fonts completely in a different way, the font is much more thinner ? why is it happening ?

[image]

i read a lot about that issue and already added the following to the netbeans.conf file

```
-J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=false
-J-Dswing.aatext=true
-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

it fixed a little, but still it is a big difference between the both,
did anyone found a proper solution for that problem or maybe one can state here that there is no solution at all ??? i am a new Netbeans user and love this IDE but this thing is driving me crazy ;((

will thank a lot !

Comment: Nice, how did you get the . to be more than one pixel? What font outputs more than one pixel on the screen for . here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fonts will look different regardless of the changes you make, as Eclipse is based upon SWT, and NetBeans on Swing; the two UI tool kits use different font rendering engines.

Some fonts look better than others in Swing. My preference in Swing (and nearly everywhere I use mono-spaced fonts, really) is [Ubuntu Mono](http://font.ubuntu.com/), but both [Deja Vu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page) and [Source Code Pro](http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2012/09/source-code-pro.html) render well in Swing, as well.

You almost certainly have the first two on your system already, and the third is easy enough to install, should you wish. I will say that the line pitch of Source Code Pro is way to large for my taste, though it is otherwise a nice font.

After enabling the JRE flags you mention, and choosing an appropriate font, the next vital item is to choose the best font size. A given font in a given rendering engine may look better or worse at a given size than in a different environment.

I find that, in Swing, Deja Vu Sans Mono looks better in even point sizes, so I typically use it at either 10pt or 12pt in NetBeans. Ubuntu Mono, on the other hand, renders much nicer at odd sizes, so I typically use it at either 11pt or 13pt in NetBeans.

Comment: Thanks !!! I was using DejaVu [without hints](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32624/ugly-fonts-in-netbeans-how-can-i-make-it-use-the-system-font), but now thanks to you i am using Source Code Pro Medium!! it looks much better than any other font that i tried. about the odd/even, are you sure the fonts size metrics in netebans is Points ? is't it in pixels?

Comment: You're welcome; if you find my answer a good one, please accept it. RE: pt vs. px, yes, I'm pretty certain the unit used in the dialog is a measure of points (these are scalable vector fonts).

Comment: I'm using now 'Droid Sans Mono', size 16 with '-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on --laf javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true'

Answer (score 2):

Font rendering is different because they use different UI libraries.
Netbeans uses swing.
Eclipse uses swt.

You can patch the jdk to get swing to respect your font rendering settings:
https://gist.github.com/aleksandara/2963640

PPA for ubuntu with patch applied:
https://launchpad.net/~no1wantdthisname/+archive/openjdk-fontfix

Comment: thanks for your input, i would accept this answer... although i can't see any difference even with this patched JDK vs original Oracle. there is probably no way to make the fonts look like in eclipse (atleast not in ubuntu)

for others, i spent too much time on trying solve this issue, if someone found a solution please share it with others.

Comment: Thank you for the patches, with fontconfig-infinality and the JDK fix installed, there's somewhat better fonts in Netbeans - but still . and : were drawing only pixels for smaller fonts. Is it just me or is font rendering kind of off on Firefox, when this is applied?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "off" without a screenshot. I would check the infinality forums for better support.